# How do I install a package from a different source, and let it update all dependencies as well?

Tags: linux, debian, apt, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm trying to install `nvidia-driver` from Debian experimental:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver=352.63-1
```

But I'm getting a dependency error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver : Depends: libgl1-nvidia-glx (= 352.63-1) but 340.96-2 is to be installed
                 Depends: libegl1-nvidia (= 352.63-1) but 340.96-2 is to be installed
                 Depends: nvidia-driver-bin (= 352.63-1) but 340.96-2 is to be installed
                 Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia (= 352.63-1) but 340.96-2 is to be installed
                 Depends: nvidia-vdpau-driver (= 352.63-1) but 340.96-2 is to be installed
                 Depends: nvidia-alternative (= 352.63-1)
                 Depends: nvidia-kernel-dkms (= 352.63-1) or
                          nvidia-kernel-352.63
                 Recommends: nvidia-settings (>= 352) but 340.93-1 is to be installed
                 Recommends: libgles1-nvidia (= 352.63-1) but 340.96-2 is to be installed
                 Recommends: libgles2-nvidia (= 352.63-1) but 340.96-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So apparently `nvidia-driver` from experimental has dependencies that apt tries to install from my default source rather than the same source as package I'm trying to install.

Is there any way to make apt-get install all necessary dependencies automatically? If it prompts me about what changes are going to be made first, so I know that I'm not messing with an extremely important package, that'd be great.

Comment: Have you seen this page? https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.apt-get.html#sect.apt-mix-distros  It is part of the Debian handbook, freely available online, which has answers for all basic level questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this when I had duplicated line in sources.list:

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie contrib main
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ non-free

Everything is fine since I replace these two lines with one

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie contrib main non-free